# Is there a way in python to execute a piece of code only if any exception is raised in a try/except block?

Tags: python, exception

I have a `try/except` block with multiple except blocks. I want to be able to execute a piece of code only if any of the exceptions are raised. Kind of like the `finally` statement, but `finally` execute regardless of if an exception was raised or not. Do I just have to add that code to each `except` block?

Comment: A short example would be useful. Is there also type-specific code? Or would catching them all at once (e.g., `except TypeError, ValueError as e:`) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your own type checking in the exception handler to deal with type-specific and general code.

```
def it_will_end_in_tears():
    raise ValueError("bad value")

try:
    val = it_will_end_in_tears()
except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
    if isinstance(e, TypeError):
        print("type error stuff")
    elif isinstance(e, ValueError):
        print("value error stuff")
    print("common stuff")
finally:
    print("finally")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of copy+pasting the code into each except block, i would declare a boolean `execute_code = False` and set it to `True` in each of the except blocks. After the whole `try/except`, add `if execute_code:`, then implement the code to execute if an exception occurred once inside the `if` block.